# DPI for EMF files

Tags: c#, image, dpi, metafile

Do EMF files have a DPI that can be set? I have an application that allows saving an image in multiple formats (including EMF). I allow the user to specify the resolution/DPI for the image(s). However, I cannot find a way to do this for a MetaFile in C#. Is this possible or does EMF not have a DPI since it is a vector graphics format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MS-EMF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230514%28v=PROT.13%29.aspx) spec, no. But ‘EMF plus’ extensions ([MS-EMFPLUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230724%28PROT.13%29.aspx)) have a header with `LogicalDpiX` and `LogicalDpiY`. This format is analogous to GDI+. I don't know what software supports it for import/export though.

Comment: This doesn't help do this in C#, but you can effectively change the resolution of emf's using PowerPoint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388048/change-resolution-of-emf-image-files-to-prevent-quality-loss-in-powerpoint

Answer (score 1):

Metafiles do not have a DPI because they do not have dots - it is a vector graphics format.  Metafiles *do* have size, which is presumably what you want.  You can set the size of a metafile (in HIMETRIC) when you call the Metafile constructor.